# Google pubsub subscriber not pulling messages when within corporate network

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have some code taken from the GCP documentation that subscribes to GCP pubsub messages. When I run this code on my personal laptop, it works fine and I can see the messages that I publish from the Google Cloud Console on the subscriber command prompt.

However, when I run this same code on my work laptop that is on the corporate network, the subscriber does not show any of the published messages. It also does not show any error messages. What could be wrong here?

```
public class PullMessages
{
    SubscriberClient subscriber;

    public PullMessages(string projectId, string subscriptionId)
    {
        SubscriptionName subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.FromProjectSubscription(projectId, subscriptionId);
        subscriber = new SubscriberClientBuilder
        {
            SubscriptionName = subscriptionName,
            EmulatorDetection = EmulatorDetection.ProductionOnly
        }.Build();
    }     

    public async Task PullMessagesAsync(string projectId, string subscriptionId, bool acknowledge)
    {
        if (subscriber == null)
            { return; }

        await subscriber.StartAsync((msg, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message {msg.MessageId} published at {msg.PublishTime.ToDateTime()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Text: '{msg.Data.ToStringUtf8()}'");

            if (msg.Data.ToStringUtf8() == "quit")
            {
                subscriber.StopAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack);
        });
    }    
}

public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting subscriber...");

        string projectId = "pubsub74";
        string subscriptionId = "my-sub";
        string topicId = "my-topic";

        var pullMessages = new PullMessages(projectId, subscriptionId);            
        await pullMessages.PullMessagesAsync(projectId, subscriptionId, true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you activate traces as per https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/help/troubleshooting#how-can-i-trace-grpc-issues and update your question with the results?

Comment: Firewall rules applied on the corporate network?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what finally worked for me. Leaving this here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

1. Add an environment variable no_proxy with the value "pubsub.googleapis.com"
2. Add entries for "oauth2.googleapis.com" and "pubsub.googleapis.com" in the hosts file usually found at this location - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts